# Where can I buy High School DxD English-translated novels?

Tags: high-school-dxd, light-novel-production

I tend to read the manga if the anime does not cover all of the story bu since *High School DxD* manga is even less developed than the anime... where can I buy the English translated (or even original not translated) novels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The novels do not have a official English translation.

Comment: @Henjin, yes unofficial ones are around. I'm not saying where as i think that might be against policy on here.